# Customize add to cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a page of getting custom values from the customer but the process will be taken place in steps like select lesnes, click next, select product frame, click next, so all the information gathered from the customer. Finally I want the details and price to be added in the cart like product details extra and plus the the extra cost to be added to the original product price.

Here is what I did: I created a new page and named template name : custom cart process and added a new page from WordPress. On the page backend I created steps; after that on the last step I added this code but it is showing read more button not add to cart, and how additional price I would pass and additional fields to it?

```
<?php 
     $product = new WC_Product( $product_id );
     echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
          sprintf( '<div class="add-to-cart-button"><a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" class="%s product_type_%s button alt-button small clearfix">%s</a></div>',
          esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
          esc_attr( $product->id ),
          $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
          esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
          esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
                                ),
     $product );
?>
```

And one more thing, when I use global $product I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add_to_cart_url() on a non-objec

Comment: How are you defining `$product_id` ?

Comment: $product_id by getting $_GET['pid']; which i had set from previous page as parameter

Comment: Please edit to include that. Because if you aren't getting an actual ID, that would explain why your `$product` isn't an actual product object. Btw, I'd advise using `wc_get_product()` instead of `new WC_Product()`.